# Why Inheritance influences Exception handling?

Tags: c++, exception

While finding answer for [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575307/c-exception-handling-in-class-hierarchies/5576040#55760) with writing test code, I got to know that private/protected inheritance changes the way exceptions are received from various classes, which was very surprising. To find the answer I referred earlier forum questions and I came across [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899563/private-inheritance-friends-and-exception-handling).

For me it's quite obvious to use `protected` inheritance for a base class with `virtual` methods. Keeping the standard aside, I wanted to know **why in C++ exception handling is restricted by inheritance when virtual method calls are Not** ?
Following snippet explains it:

```
struct Base { virtual void printError () = 0; };
class Derived : protected Base { void printError () { } };

int main ()
{
try {
  throw new Derived;
}
catch(Base *p) { p->printError(); }  // Ideal; but not invoked
catch(void *p) { ((Base*)p)->printError(); } // Ugly; but only way to invoke
}
```

**Edit:**
If we consider the privacy regard as an answer; accepted. But then why it's applicable only for `catch()` receiving base pointers, while it's not applicable for functions receiving base pointers ?

Comment: minor note, you don't have to use `new` in `throw` statements, you only risk introducing memory leaks by doing so. Instead use `throw Derived();` and catch by reference `Base&`. Also, it's definitely not obvious to me why someone would use `protected` inheritance if the base class has virtual methods, I think you got something wrong here... And finally, exceptions class should generally inherit from `std::exception` and overload `char const* what() const`.

Comment: @Matthieu, thanks, but above code was just for demo purpose. Catching by reference is not possible in this case since you can't catch `void&`; however I also prefer catching by references. Depending on my design, I would want that Interface(here `Base`) class methods (especially virtual) should not be called by any of its Children in other namespaces.

Comment: it's always possible to redefine a virtual method, even if it's private to the base class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The meaning of `private` and `protected` inheritance is that no one outside of the class or class hierarchy can know about the inheritance. This is the same way as no one outside the class can know about a private member.
Catching a derived class by its base class revealed to the catcher that the derived class is infact derived from the base class and is a breach of the privacy of the inheritance.

Comment: Why there is a problem only while `catch`; when the same scenario is applicable to a function call, it's easily acceptable!

Comment: @iammilind, wrong, you get a similar error when you try to privately Derived class to a function with a Base& argument. Test it for yourself.

Answer (score 5):

`protected` inheritance means only `Derived` and its subclasses "knows" it also is-a `Base`. `main`, and the catch statement, doesn't "know" this. This is the point of inheriting with a specific access.

Virtual dispatch doesn't care about this - if you have access to call a virtual function, then virtual dispatch *is* used.

In your sample, you cannot use a `Derived` as if it was a `Base` anywhere else in the scope of `main` - so it makes sense that you can't do it in the `catch` either